# In this infant (<500 million years) solar system, how far would each orbit be to be stable?

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, stars, solar-system

Here's the story:  There is a solar system that is still a baby, less than 500 million years old.

[image]

There are a total of eight stars clumped into four binaries, each one with its  own habitable zone.  But the odd thing is that the habitable worlds (*and I say that with irony, as there are plenty of plates, water and atmosphere but zero traces of life*) are older than the stars, which would indicate that these stars may have stolen the planets from neighboring solar systems.  Here are the specified details of each star:

- A: F0, 130% solar width, 170% solar mass, 600% solar luminosity
- B: F0, 130% solar width, 170% solar mass, 600% solar luminosity
- C: F5, 120% solar width, 130% solar mass, 250% solar luminosity
- D: G0, 105% solar width, 110% solar mass, 126% solar luminosity
- E: G0, 105% solar width, 110% solar mass, 126% solar luminosity
- F: G0, 105% solar width, 110% solar mass, 126% solar luminosity
- G: G0, 105% solar width, 110% solar mass, 126% solar luminosity
- H: K0, 85% solar width, 78% solar mass, 40% solar luminosity

The orbit between E and F is the only one specified, at 0.46 AUs, or 42,780,000 miles from each other.  But as for the rest, **how far will each orbit be to be stable?**

Comment: Determining the stability of even simple systems is a challenge. You've got eight. I'd guess it would require months of effort to give this a reasonable answer. Unless it turns out there is some obvious instability that can be detected quite quickly.

Comment: With the information so far, we can tell that the E-F pair will take about 27days3hours to complete an orbit around each other and end up back in their starting positions relative to each other.  I've got an answer in progress, but in order to complete it, I'll need more information about the orbital periods of other sets in the system.  Estimates are fine, since I'll have to adjust them for my answer to work.  Roughly how long do you expect it to take for each pair to orbit each other?  Roughly how long for the AB pair to orbit the CD pair?  How long for the ABCD set to orbit EFGH? etc.